# Value conversion between ctypes and python is wrong

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am having trouble with type conversion between C and python with the following code:

**example.c:**

```
long *ex_func(void)
{
    long arr[2] = {0L, 0L};
    return arr;
}
```

**compiled via:**

```
gcc -shared -Wall -o example.so -fPIC example.c
```

**and the python code:**

```
import ctypes
f = ctypes.CDLL("./example.so").ex_func
f.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long * 2)
for i in f().contents:
    print i
```

prints me the values:

```
0
140715720703376
```

Same also happens chen I use `ctypes.c_longlong`

And just for the fun of it I once used `c_int` and it would print:

```
1
0
```

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`long arr[2]` is a local array on the stack.  Returning the address of that array is undefined behavior.

You could make the array `static long arr[2]` and it would work.

Comment: Thanks, I also got that warning from the compiler but didn't know what to make of it. Is there a way to do this without static?

Comment: `malloc`, but then you'd have to `free` it, or pass a buffer and a size from Python using `ctypes.create_string_buffer` so Python manages the memory instead.